# Trouble understanding closure details - setTimeout within for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding why the first snippet below executes all five `console.log`'s quickly, while the second snippet executes the `console.log`'s one second apart.

I understand that a closure (aka a function + the scope in which it was declared) is needed to "close" over the value of `i` at various points in the `for` loop.

I understand that in the first snippet, the innermost function is immediately invoked, while the second snippet's innermost function is not immediately invoked.

And yet, it does not feel clear to me what is actually happening.

Some questions:

- In the first snippet, is the innermost function executing over separate ticks?
- In the first snippet, why does the innermost function execute so quickly?
- In the second snippet, why does the innermost function execute over one second intervals?

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(
    (function (x) {
      (function () {
        console.log(x)
      })(i)
    })(i),
    i * 1000
  )
}
```

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(
    (function (x) {
      return (function () {
        console.log(x)
      })
    })(i),
    i * 1000
  )
}
```

**Note:** I do understand that using `let` makes this much easier, but I'm trying to understand this in terms of closures.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(
    function () {
      console.log(i)
    },
    i * 1000
  )
}
```

Comment: well, you have 3 correct answers explaining the same thing in 3 different ways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the mechanics of closures. This is 100% caused by how functions work.

Now, let's tease apart the two different functions. For clarity I'm going to completely remove the for loop:

1:

```
var i = 1; // We simply hardcode `i` for this demo.

function a (x) {
    (function(){
      console.log(x);
    })(i); // immediately call this function

    // THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT PART OF THE CODE
    // Yes, this space with no code at all at the end of
    // this function is the MOST IMPORTANT part of the code.
    // This absence of code represents "return undefined".
    // All functions that return nothing returns undefined.
}

setTimeout(a(i),i * 1000);
```

Note: remember that `a()` returns `undefined`. So the setTimeout is actually:

```
setTimeout(undefined,1000);
```

"Helpfully", if you pass undefined to `setTimeout` it will gracefully accept it and not generate any errors.

It should also be obvious that you directly call `console.log` when calling `a()`.

Now let's look at the other code:

2:

```
var i = 1;

function b (x) {
  return (function () {
    console.log(x)
  }) // <--- note you are not calling the inner function at all
}

setTimeout(b(i), i * 1000);
```

Note that since `b()` returns a function `setTimeout` will call the function returned by `b()` (the one that calls console.log) after 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

The difference here is less about how closures work and more about how `setTimeoute()` works. `setTimeout` will invoke the passed in function sometime after the time passed in. So you pass it a function:

```
setTimeout(someFunction, 1000)
```

And in a 1000 milliseconds or so it executes `someFunction()`

In the first example you are executing the functions before `setTimout` ever has a chance to by immediately calling `someFunction()`. By the time `setTimeout` gets around to it, it doesn't have a function to call -- just the return values of the function you already called. The functions are being called synchronously on the current tick.

You can think of it like passing a callback. If you pass a callback to a function like this `someFunction(null, cb)` it can execute it later with `cb()`, but if you pass `someFunction(null, cb())` it will receive the return value of cb rather than cb itself. If that's a function it will call that.

In the second example you immediately execute the outside function, but return a function the `setTimeout` can call later. That is what it does, which is why this works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, but tricky :)

In first example, your creating and executing anonymous functions. Then you return undefined to the setTimeout. setTimeout will execute nothing. Thats why it executes quickly.

In second example, your creating and executing an anonymous function that creates another anonymous function and return it to setTimeout. Then setTimeout will execute it.

See my comments:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(
    (function (x) {
      (function () {
        console.log(x)
      })(i)  -> create and EXECUTE anonymous function (execute it right away)
    })(i), -> create and execute anonymous function. returns undefined
    i * 1000
  )
}


for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(
    (function (x) {
      return (function () {
        console.log(x)
      })
    })(i), -> create and execute anonymous function. returns a new function
    i * 1000
  )
}
```